# Race condition in react when updating redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a chess game using React + Redux. I have a function called allValidMoves which is called when a piece is dragging. It updates redux state that stores all possible valid Moves. At the same time, I have 64 square components that are trying to access this Map as soon as the piece starts dragging. The problem is that 
some Squares are getting the previous redux state; I am using react-dnd for drag and drop

```
const pieces = () => {

  if(isDragging){
   calculateValidMoves();
  }

}

function calculateValidMoves() {
   arr = {};
   ....

   store.dispatch(update_validMoves('UPDATE',arr))


}

const Squares = (props) => {

   arr = store.validMoves.getState()

   if(arr.get(props.index)){
      doSomething
   }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see on your code, i think u wanna get store in action ?
Better use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for get State inside action.
And that redux-thunk is asynchronous. So you can avoid that race condition with await / callback on action redux.